# SQLAlchemy - Python Programming Error 'Converting decimal loses precision', 'HY000'

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am using SQL Alchemy engine along with pandas and trying to implement `fast_executemany=True` but I am getting this error while I tried to insert df frames rows to a SQL SERVER DB.

My code is something like this

```
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://@SERVER/DATABASE?driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server',
                       encoding="utf-8", fast_executemany=True)
conn = engine.connect()
```

Then I split the dataframe into chunks and apply pd.to_sql to each chunk

```
chunksize = int(len(df) / 10) # 10%
with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
    for i, cdf in enumerate(chunker(df, chunksize)):
        replace_var = "replace" if i == 0 else "append"
        cdf.to_sql(output_table_name, con=engine, schema=output_schema, if_exists=replace_var, index=False)
        pbar.update(chunksize)
```

After trying to run the first chunk I have the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\parquet_import_to_sql\parquet_import.py", line 97, in <module>
    insert_with_progress(df, engine, table_output, schema)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\parquet_import_to_sql\parquet_import.py", line 25, in insert_with_progress
    cdf.to_sql(output_table_name, con=engine, schema=output_schema, if_exists=replace_var, index=False)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2872, in to_sql
    sql.to_sql(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 717, in to_sql
    pandas_sql.to_sql(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1761, in to_sql
    sql_engine.insert_records(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1350, in insert_records
    raise err
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 1340, in insert_records
    table.insert(chunksize=chunksize, method=method)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 967, in insert
    exec_insert(conn, keys, chunk_iter)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 882, in _execute_insert
    conn.execute(self.table.insert(), data)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1286, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params, _EMPTY_EXECUTION_OPTS)
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 323, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1478, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1842, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2023, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1779, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_executemany(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\dialects\mssql\pyodbc.py", line 550, in do_executemany
    super(MSDialect_pyodbc, self).do_executemany(
  File "X:\avelazquez\retail\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 714, in do_executemany
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Converting decimal loses precision', 'HY000')
```

Just to complete the story I was having a MemoryError before this but updated SQLAlchemy to the latest version and put it as a driver ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server, but now I have this issue.

I haven't found much on the web, some people talking to use `dtype` to change the precision of the column where I have the error but I have 70 columns and most of the are numerics :P

Comment: Check the table that is created by the initial `.to_sql()` call. Are the supposedly numeric columns created as `varchar(max)`?

Comment: Hi Gord, it works! I look for numeric columns that pandas identified as "object" and I changed one by one in pandas. Thanks! 
Do you think how I can overcome this issue in a more systematic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gord was right, there were numeric columns created as varchar(max). I had to cast them manually while creating dataframe

Comment: Glad the fix worked! Would you mind sharing a code snippet that shows the change you made that fixed it? This would help others who have the same issue!

Comment: How exactly did you cast them manually?

Comment: Hi @Lisle, using astype reading the file with Pandas